# problems with calendar, does not load events that already exist in the database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have a working calendar, insert new events, update well and delete the event too

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Laravel Fullcalender Add/Update/Delete Event Example Tutorial - Tutsmake.com</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  </head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@3.9.0/dist/fullcalendar.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@3.9.0/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="response"></div>
      <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

here follows the javascript code which is where everything works

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var SITEURL = "{{url('/')}}";
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }

    });
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      editable: true,
      events: SITEURL + "fullcalendar",
      displayEventTime: true,
      editable: true,
      eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
        if (event.allDay === 'true') {
          event.allDay = true;
        } else {
          event.allDay = false;
        }
      },
      selectable: true,
      selectHelper: true,
      select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
        if (title) {
          var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
          var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
          $.ajax({
            url: SITEURL + "/fullcalendar/create",
            data: 'title=' + title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
              displayMessage("Added Successfully");
            }
          });
          calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
              title: title,
              start: start,
              end: end,
              allDay: allDay
            },
            true
          );
        }
        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
      },
      eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        $.ajax({
          url: SITEURL + '/fullcalendar/update',
          data: 'title=' + event.title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end + '&id=' + event.id,
          type: "POST",
          success: function(response) {
            displayMessage("Updated Successfully");
          }
        });
      },
      eventClick: function(event) {
        var deleteMsg = confirm("Do you really want to delete?");
        if (deleteMsg) {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: SITEURL + '/fullcalendar/delete',
            data: "&id=" + event.id,
            success: function(response) {
              if (parseInt(response) > 0) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                displayMessage("Deleted Successfully");
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });

  function displayMessage(message) {
    $(".response").html("<div class='success'>" + message + "</div>");
    setInterval(function() {
      $(".success").fadeOut();
    }, 1000);
  }

</script>
```

the problem that is appearing to me is that when I enter the page, the calendar should already show the events created and saved in the database, which is not happening. Also when creating a new event, if after that you update the page, it no longer appears even though it remains registered in the database, how can I solve the problem?

```
public function index()
    {
        if(request()->ajax()) 
        {
 
         $start = (!empty($_GET["start"])) ? ($_GET["start"]) : ('');
         $end = (!empty($_GET["end"])) ? ($_GET["end"]) : ('');
 
         $data = Event::whereDate('start', '>=', $start)->whereDate('end',   '<=', $end)->get(['id','title','start', 'end']);
         return Response::json($data);
        }
        return view('fullcalendar');
    }
    
   
    public function create(Request $request)
    {  
        $insertArr = [ 'title' => $request->title,
                       'start' => $request->start,
                       'end' => $request->end
                    ];
        $event = Event::insert($insertArr);   
        return Response::json($event);
    }
     
 
    public function update(Request $request)
    {   
        $where = array('id' => $request->id);
        $updateArr = ['title' => $request->title,'start' => $request->start, 'end' => $request->end];
        $event  = Event::where($where)->update($updateArr);
 
        return Response::json($event);
    } 
 
 
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $event = Event::where('id',$request->id)->delete();
   
        return Response::json($event);
    }
```

Comment: In the future please make sure your code is formatted so that it is readable.

Comment: Where is the code get the events from your DB to your client? where is the code that enter the events into your calendar?

Comment: @Art3mix I added the functions of the controller

Comment: @Phix Thank you for your help

Comment: @Art3mix can you help me?

Comment: `the calendar should already show the events created and saved in the database, which is not happening`...clearly something is wrong with your loading process. Have you debugged it at all? Do you know how to debug AJAX requests, and how to debug PHP? There's nothing _obviously_ wrong with your code, but perhaps it crashes somehow, or the data returned isn't in a format that fullCalendar understands. You need to do some basic debugging and narrow down the problem.

Comment: `Also when creating a new event, if after that you update the page, it no longer appears even though it remains registered in the database`...this sounds like it's probably a symptom of the same problem. Again...what debugging have you done? We can't debug your code for you. If the issue isn't obvious purely from looking at the code, then you need to give us more information to work with.